# Framework 7 How to add javascripts in another page?

Tags: html-framework-7

I make a website with framework 7. I get trouble when to active a javascripts in another page.
My javascripts is:

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
}}
```

Javascripts working in homepage, but when I load another page, it is not working. I know it must be install in my-app.js but I do not know how to install.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://framework7.io/docs/pages.html#page-data), here I have got:

If you have a page with name `other-page`. Page name will found in :

```
 `<div class="pages">
    <div class="page" data-page="other-page">
      <div class="page-content">
        <!--  ... page content goes here ... -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`
```

so, you can execute your function inside the page callback :

```
// In page callbacks:
myApp.onPageInit('other-page', function (page) { 
    // "page" variable contains all required information about loaded and initialized page 
    // write your function here
});
```

And before it, make sure you have initialize your app.

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    pushState: true,
    swipePanel: 'left',
    // ... other parameters
});
```